# Using Powershell to Append a table to the end of an Excel File (The Last Row)

Tags: excel, powershell, ms-office

I've written a Powershell script that copies a table from Microsoft Word and pastes them to an excel document.  I want to append it after the last used row in column A.

I got this code so far:

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$Excel.Visible = $True

$ExcelWordBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelPath)

$ExcelWorkSheet = $Excel.WorkSheets.item("Sheet1")

$ExcelWorkSheet.activate()
```

This is where I get confused, I want to be able to find the last row that is used in the Excel WorkSheet.

```
$lastRow = $ExcelWorkSheet.UsedRange.rows("A").count

$nextRow = $lastRow + 1

$ExcelWorkSheet.Range("A$nextRow").Select

$ExcelWorkSheet.Paste()
```

---

I feel like I'm so close after this. I was trying to use the UsedRange property in the Office Interlop to determine the last row in the Excel WorkSheet. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.usedrange(v=vs.80).aspx) Any ideas?

Comment: The question doesn't (yet) have any description of what your problem/bug/error/result is. What goes wrong? What had you expected?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks I ended up going a different route that's more dynamic instead of using "A9924082480198" as the end of the range.

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $True
$ExcelWordBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelPath)
$ExcelWorkSheet = $Excel.WorkSheets.item("sheet1")
$ExcelWorkSheet.activate()

$lastRow = $ExcelWorkSheet.UsedRange.rows.count + 1
$Excel.Range("A" + $lastrow).Activate()
$ExcelWorksheet.Paste()
```

Answer (score 1):

The object returned by `$ExcelWorkSheet.UsedRange` has a property `rows` (not a method, you can't use a parameter). This means that `$ExcelWorkSheet.UsedRange.rows.count` will work, but won't give you the desired result (it will give you the row number of the las trow for the longest column).

To append something after the last used cell in column A, try the following:

```
$xldown = -4121 # see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241212(v=office.12).aspx
$xlup = -4162
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $True
$ExcelWordBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelPath)
$ExcelWorkSheet = $Excel.WorkSheets.item("Sheet1")
$ExcelWorkSheet.activate()

# Find the last used cell
$lastRow = $ExcelWorksheet.cells.Range("A1048576").End($xlup).row

$nextRow = $lastRow + 1
$range = $ExcelWorkSheet.Range("A$nextRow")
$ExcelWorkSheet.Paste($range)
```