# Append from the last row on-wards Excel & Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am currently working on a script that would keep track of the size of databases across different network servers. I am outputting the results to an excel, this will run every day, hence, I need to know how I can get the last row which contains data and append from there on-wards.

```
#Creates heading on an excel file if the file did not exist previously
Function CreateExcelWithHeadings($intRow, $Sheet)
{
$intRow++
#Create column headers
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1)= "Date"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1).Font.Size = 12
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1).Font.Bold = $True

$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2) = "Server"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2).Font.Size = 12
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2).Font.Bold = $True

#$intRow++
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,3) = "Database"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,3).Font.Bold = $True
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,4) = "Data Name"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,4).Font.Bold = $True
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,5) = "Data File"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,5).Font.Bold = $True
$sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,6) = "Data Size (MB)"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,6).Font.Bold = $True
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,7) = "Data Used Space (MB)"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,7).Font.Bold = $True
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,8) = "Log Name"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,8).Font.Bold = $True
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,9) = "Log Size (MB)"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,9).Font.Bold = $True
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,10) = "Log Used Space (MB)"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,10).Font.Bold = $True
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,11) = "Log File"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,11).Font.Bold = $True  
}
# initalize variables 
$serverList = "C:\Database Monitor\sqlservers.txt"
$filepath ='C:\Database Monitor\Log Files\' 
$filename = 'database_logging.xlsx' 
#Create a new Excel object using COM 
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
# check if file path exists, if its doesn't create one with the proper headings
If (-not (Test-Path -path $filepath))
{
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $filepath
$Excel.visible = $True
$Excel = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
$Sheet = $Excel.Worksheets.Item(1)
CreateExcelWithheadings 0 $Sheet
$Sheet.SaveAs($filepath+$filename)
#WritetoExcel($serverList, 0)

}
Else
{
$Excel.visible = $True
$Excel = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($filepath)
$Sheet = $Excel.Worksheets.Item(1)
$ExcelWorkSheet.activate()
#$lastRow = 
 }
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8452408/775544 Not quite a duplicate but it may help get what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I already looked at that it didn't really help. I'm not to sure why they specified a range. If you can explain it that would be great.