# How to get a specific error line in powershell and pipe it into excel?

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I am currently writing a script in powershell that performs a test move of resources in Azure. I am currently receiving an error

Invoke-AzResourceAction : ResourceMoveNotSupported : Resource move is not supported for resource types 'microsoft.insights/activityLogAlerts'.
CorrelationId: SomeLongStringOfRandomStuff
At C:\Users\pcname\Documents\NewScript.ps1:16 char:9

- ```
      Invoke-AzResourceAction -Action validateMoveResources -Resour ...
  ```
- ```
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Invoke-AzResourceAction], ErrorResponseMessageException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.InvokAzureResourceActionCmdlet

I would like to be able to retrieve the correlation ID, and put that into an Excel sheet, how can I filter for this? I can't use a static substring as the names can be extremely difficult, however this error is on its own line, how can I go about this?

```
try
{
    Invoke-AzResourceAction -Action validateMoveResources -ResourceId $ResourceGroupID -Parameters @{ resources=@($ResourceID);targetResourceGroup = $resource.TargetResourceGroup }
    Write-Host $ResourceID + " Has been moved succesfully"
 
}
catch
{
    Write-Host $_.CorrelationID #This should be the object that is returned
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to be able to retrieve the correlation ID

If your **Invoke-AzResourceAction** gives the ***correlationId*** object we can retrieve it.

In a PowerShell, **Errors and Exceptions are structured objects**. So we can format to our own way.

Refer [Caching Error in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38421525/15997690).

> and put that into an Excel sheet

To pipe your error message into excel you can use the **`ConvertTo-Csv`**.  First you have to add your error messages into **array of objects** and use **`ConvertTo-Csv`**.

Refer to [Append PowerShell output to an Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35611746/15997690)

Comment: So would I do something like this inside my catch?
 $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.CorrelationId

Comment: Can you check if your correlationId has a object. if it was object we can retrieve using `$_.<objectName>`. If not you can construct your format `$formatstring -f $fields` and use like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38421525/15997690)

Comment: I managed to come right, thank you so much, Unfortunately the error message read to me was not broken up into an object, however a little string manipulation did the trick!

Comment: yes. using convert-csv we can achieve this.