# Last 8 used rows in excel. Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, copy-paste

I've looked all over and I can't seem to find an answer for this.  Instead of selecting from A1 to G8, I just want it to select the last 8 USED rows in the import it creates.  Not sure what to use here.

```
$pathtsv = "C:\xxxxxx.mdf"
$pathxlsx = "C:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xlsx"

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$Excel.Visible=$true 

$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($pathxlsx) 
$TempWorkbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Opentext($pathtsv) 

$temp = $excel.Workbooks.Item(2) 
$temp = $temp.Worksheets.Item(1) 
$CopyRange = $temp.Range("A1:G8") 
$CopyRange.Copy()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In [Using Powershell to Append a table to the end of an Excel File (The Last Row)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452408/using-powershell-to-append-a-table-to-the-end-of-an-excel-file-the-last-row) I think you can find part of the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [`ImportExcel` module by Doug Finke](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/4.0.4) rather than using Excel as a COM Object. Then the Excel document can be easily imported as a PowerShell object which can then be filtered by `Select-Object -Last 8` or `$ImportedExcelObject[-8..-1]` then reexported in what I assume a Tab Delimited format.

```
Install-Module ImportExcel

$pathtsv = "C:\xxxxxx.mdf"
$pathxlsx = "C:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xlsx"

Import-Excel $pathxlsx | Select-Object -Last 8 | Export-CSV $pathtsv -Delimiter "`t"
```

Note: The Install-Module command is included by default in PowerShell 5+.

---

Here is the updated code for going the opposite way from a tsv to a a specific row and column in an Excel document using the `Export-Excel` cmdlet from the ImportExcel Module.

```
Install-Module ImportExcel

$pathtsv = 'C:\xxxxxx.mdf'
$templatexls = 'C:\yyyyyyyyyy.xlsx'
$pathxlsx = 'C:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xlsx'

Copy-Item $templatexls $pathxlsx
Import-CSV $pathtsv -Delimiter "`t" | Select-Object -Last 8 | Export-Excel -Path $pathxlsx -WorksheetName 'Sheet1' -Show -StartRow 3 -StartColumn 1 -NoHeader
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!  The goal is to get it out of the TSV and get it into an excel template.  I just want to change what it is copying from (currently A1:G8) to the last 8 used rows.   I have the rest of the script setup, I just need to be able to change what is being copied, as the Tab delimited file I am pulling from is cumulative.